# Find $\lfloor z \rfloor $ given that $z=(\{\sqrt{3}\}^2-2\{\sqrt{2}\}^2)/(\{\sqrt{3}\}-2\{\sqrt{2}\})$

Tags: functions, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the greatest integer function, and $\{x\}=x-[x]$ the fractional part of $x$. If $$z=\cfrac{\{\sqrt{3}\}^2-2\{\sqrt{2}\}^2}{\{\sqrt{3}\}-2\{\sqrt{2}\}}$$ find $\lfloor z \rfloor $

> **My attempt**

$$z=\cfrac{\{\sqrt{3}\}^2-2\{\sqrt{2}\}^2}{\{\sqrt{3}\}-2\{\sqrt{2}\}}=\cfrac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2-2(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}{\sqrt{3}-1-2\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)}=\cfrac{3+1-2(3 -2\sqrt{2})}{\sqrt{3}-1-2\cdot \sqrt{2}+2}$$

After rationalizing I have $$z=\cfrac{4\sqrt{2}+4\sqrt{6}-2-2\sqrt{3}}{-2} $$ (I hope I haven't made any careless mistake now )

Now I am stuck as I don't know how I should take $\lfloor z \rfloor$ as I don't have that if $x=\cfrac{a}{b}$ then $\lfloor x \rfloor =\cfrac{\lfloor a \rfloor}{\lfloor b \rfloor}$ .

I also think I haven't noticed a more straightforward way to do the problem ...

Comment: Rationalize the denominator

Comment: Note $\{\sqrt{2}\}=\sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: Oops,sorry let me edit !

Comment: The best was to not rationalize D:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have

\begin{align*}
z = \cfrac{(\sqrt{3}-1)^2-2(\sqrt{2}-1)^2}{\sqrt{3}-1-2\cdot (\sqrt{2}-1)} &= \frac{3+1-2\sqrt{3}-2(2+1-2\sqrt2)}{\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt2+1}\\
&= \frac{-2\sqrt3 + 4\sqrt2-2}{\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt2+1}\\
&= -2\frac{\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt2+1}{\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt2+1}\\
&= -2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Me dumb, I didn't see that ,neat ! (thank you)